# Style expander buttons of TreeView

Tags: wpf, triggers, treeview, styles, expander

Here is my XAML:

```
            <Style x:Key="ExpanderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Image Source="/Images/SHCalendarLeftArrow.tiff" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

So what I want is so that if the item is expanded, then display a different image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I used a trigger

```
<Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="False">
                            <Setter x:Name="Expander_Expanded"
                                    TargetName="Expander_Normal" Property="Source"
                                    Value="/Images/SHCalendarLeftArrow.tiff" />
                        </Trigger>
```